# How do I use adjectives like　気持ち悪い?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

At the moment I can only remember 気持ちいい and 気持ち悪い, but I am sure there are more adjectives like this. They consist of a noun and then an adjective. I'm confused about them because I've seen 気持ちの悪い and I don't know how this would translate (feeling's bad?).

If I wanted to use adjectives like this on their own, do I just say it like 「それが気持ち悪い」? Also, if I wanted to modify a noun, would I then use it like so: 「気持ちの悪い人」?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's taken as either one adjective or combination of a noun and an adjective.

So, you can say either それが 気持ち悪い or それが 気持ちが 悪い, likewise 気持ち悪い人 or 気持ちの悪い人 in modifying clauses.